# Rotor VS Caliper VS Pad compatibility

Tags: brakes, brake-pads, rotor, ice

It might be a silly question, but it's not clear to me (peabrain here)

I'm using BR-R317 calipers with G03S pads and RT30 rotors. It's my understanding that Shimano calipers and rotors are compatible, in a general, right?

Anyways... I'm riding a gravel setup with Sora STIs, so not willing to change them out to switch to hydraulic brakes/calipers etc.

I just bought a pair of SM-RT81 rotors and I would like to keep the calipers however.  My concern is regarding the pads; can I keep using the same model? would that work fine? should I move to a another pad model?

I friend of mine has a similar setup, just that he is using MT800 rotors, and suggest me to use G02S pads; if I'm not mistaken, G02S is just the previous version of G03S - correct?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of compatibility, the main attention point is about the pad type: resin/organic or metallic. Metal pads are able to withstand higher temperatures, and so you need to make sure that the braking system is designed to evacuate that heat. Some rotors are spec'd to be used with resin pads and/or metal pads.

In your case, it's quite easy: the SM-RT81 are compatible with both kinds of pads, so you can keep your current setup.

Regarding your question about G02S/G03S:  G03S is indeed a more durable upgrade of the G02S.

Comment: thanks by taking time answering the question. I just received the RT81 rotors - they're beautiful :) - I didnt consider the heat issue you mentioned about using metal pads, so as the calipers are not icetech compatible, I'm gonna keep resin ones. mainly concern was inded about compatibility overall. thanks.